# Unreal Engine 4 multiplayer LAN - Second player not spawning

Tags: networking, multiplayer, lan, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I am trying to set up a basic LAN two player game on UE4, I have been able to do the following:

- Host a game
- Search for games being hosted
- Join the hosted game (partly)

I need help with the following:

- Spawning the second players character.
- Second player to control the second spawned character.

At the moment when my second game instance joins the hosted instance however the camera stays fixed in the starting spot with no spawned character to move. It has joined the hosted game because I can see the first player moving around from player two's screen.

The picture of the blueprints are below. Let me know if you need more info, thanks for the help!!  :)

https://s30.postimg.org/opxn89pgh/2.png

https://s30.postimg.org/km19tiiw1/6.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error in the game mode. i needed to change default pawn class to `thirdpersoncharactor`.